# How to reflect a class from its property value?

Tags: c#, system.reflection

Lets suppose, we have these three types:

```
class class1{ public static int serial=1};
class class2{ public static int serial=2};
class class3{ public static int serial=3};
```

The serial could be a static field or a property like:

```
class class1{ public override byte serial {get{return 0x01; }}};
```

In my application I receive the serial value from somewhere and need to reflect the appropriate class. Is that possible to reflect any of these types using the serial field of that item? Do I have to create a map table between serial id and class name to find the related class name for reflection? Or System.Reflection allows me to find the class directly from its *field or property value*? I think it would be a better way because We do not need to edit the table for new types.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: are those fields static?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can get the type by the field's value:

```
var type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
           .GetTypes()
           .FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetField("serial") != null && 
                               (int)x.GetField("serial").GetValue(null) == 2)
```

If the types are defined in another assembly rather than the currently executing assembly then you need to first get that assembly using the methods in `Assembly` class (like `Load`, `LoadFrom`, `LoadFile`).

And also fields should be `static` in order this to work, otherwise you need an instance to get field value and pass it to `GetValue` method instead of *null*.

Comment: It might be wise to add a note about the requirement that the field must be static for this to work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So what if I had a field like this: public override byte serial { get { return 0x2C; } } Can I use that in your solution? these classes are derived from an abstract class with an abstract property serial. I override this field for each derived class.

Comment: that is not a field but a property. and yes you can just change GetField to GetProperty.but  since it's an instance member, you need an instance to get its value.

Comment: @a.toraby: You should update your question for more corrective

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately It doesn't work for me. It doesn't have GetField method. Maybe its because My project type is PCL. Could you possibly help me in this regard? I tried: `type.DefinedTypes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetDeclaredProperty("serial") != null && (byte)x.GetDeclaredProperty("serial").GetValue(null) == val);` but it throws System.Reflection.TargetException: Non-static method requires a target. Thanks in advance