# How to return string value depending on type of generic

Tags: c#, generics

I have this code to get a list of Star Wars API objects:

```
public static async Task<IList<T>> Get<T>() 
    where T : SWAPIEntity
{
    var entities = new List<T>();
    var rootUrl = (string)typeof(T).GetProperty("rootUrl").GetValue(null);

    var url = $"{baseUrl}/{rootUrl}";

    var result = await GetResult<T>(url);
    entities.AddRange(result.results);

    while (result.next != null)
    {
        result = await GetResult<T>(result.next);
        entities.AddRange(result.results);
    }

    return entities;
}
```

Where I want `rootUrl` to depend on which type of `SWAPIEntity` is being passed in for `T`.

The code above throws

> "Non-static method requires a target."

Where `SWAPIEntity`:

```
public class SWAPIEntity 
{
    public string name { get; }
}
```

and `SWAPIEntity`:

```
public class SWAPIEntity 
{
    public string name { get; }
}
```

and `Planet`:

```
public class Planet : SWAPIEntity
{
    public string rootUrl { get; } = "planets";

    public string climate { get; set; }
}
```

And I call it with

```
await StarWarsApi.Get<Planet>();
```

How can I get the value of `rootUrl` depending on which type of `SWAPIEntity` I am trying to get?

Comment: Possibly related: [what-does-system-reflection-targetexception-non-static-method-requires-a-target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28342206/what-does-system-reflection-targetexception-non-static-method-requires-a-target)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error says it all.

You are trying to call a non-static member, so you need to pass an Instance. I guess the simple solution for you is to make this property `static`.

```
public class Planet : SWAPIEntity
{
    public static string rootUrl { get; } = "planets";
    // Or newer simpler syntax:
    // public static string rootUrl => "planets";
    public string climate { get; set; }
}
```